# Auto reloading python Flask app upon code changes

Tags: python, apache, flask

I'm investigating how to develop a decent web app with Python. Since I don't want some high-order structures to get in my way, my choice fell on the lightweight [Flask framework](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). Time will tell if this was the right choice.

So, now I've set up an Apache server with mod_wsgi, and my test site is running fine. However, I'd like to speed up the development routine by making the site automatically reload upon any changes in py or template files I make. I see that any changes in site's .wsgi file causes reloading (even without WSGIScriptReloading On in the apache config file), but I still have to prod it manually (ie, insert extra linebreak, save). Is there some way how to cause reload when I edit some of the app's py files? Or, I am expected to use IDE that refreshes the .wsgi file for me?

Answer (score 544, accepted):

Run the `flask run` CLI command with [debug mode](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/quickstart/#debug-mode) enabled, which will automatically enable the reloader. As of Flask 2.2, you can pass `--app` and `--debug` options on the command line.

```
$ flask --app main.py --debug run
```

`--app` can also be set to `module:app` or `module:create_app` instead of `module.py`. [See the docs for a full explanation.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/cli/#application-discovery)

More options are available with:

```
$ flask run --help
```

Prior to Flask 2.2, you needed to set the `FLASK_APP` and `FLASK_ENV=development` environment variables.

```
$ export FLASK_APP=main.py
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

It is still possible to set `FLASK_APP` and `FLASK_DEBUG=1` in Flask 2.2.

Answer (score 336):

If you are talking about test/dev environments, then just use the debug option. It will auto-reload the flask app when a code change happens.

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Or, from the shell:

```
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ flask run
```

http://flask.palletsprojects.com/quickstart/#debug-mode

Comment: This works only when you run the site via the built-in development server. But not when running it via wsgi, on Apache. And I don't insist I really need to run it on Apache, so maybe what you suggest is the right way to do it.

Comment: correct. In dev environment, the built in server works really well and you don't need to reinvent the wheel for reloading the app. I strongly advise you just use the built in server for dev. purposes. In prod anyway, you don't want to auto reload the app at every code change.

Comment: Another ways is flask --app app --debug run

Answer (score 63):

## In test/development environments

The werkzeug debugger already has an 'auto reload' function available that can be enabled by doing one of the following:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

or

```
app.debug = True
```

You can also use a separate configuration file to manage all your setup if you need be. For example I use 'settings.py' with a 'DEBUG = True' option. Importing this file is easy too;

```
app.config.from_object('application.settings')
```

However this is not suitable for a production environment.

## Production environment

Personally I chose Nginx + uWSGI over Apache + mod_wsgi for a few performance reasons but also the configuration options. The [touch-reload](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#touch-reload) option allows you to specify a file/folder that will cause the uWSGI application to reload your newly deployed flask app.

For example, your update script pulls your newest changes down and touches 'reload_me.txt' file. Your uWSGI ini script (which is kept up by Supervisord - obviously) has this line in it somewhere:

```
touch-reload = '/opt/virtual_environments/application/reload_me.txt'
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. I simplified it a bit. Create a bash script that touches itself when executed. Thus you only need to launch it when you want a reload. My solution:

    # touch_me_and_reload.sh
    touch $0

Comment: @Ewan. where is the touch-reload line supposed to be in? the [program:uwsig] section or the [supervisord] section?

Comment: @user805981- neither, a separate uwsgi configuration `.ini` file. If you read the documentation on "touch-reload" it's in the uWSGI, not supervisor, configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this. `app.run(debug=True)` fails, but setting the environmental variable works.

Answer (score 26):

If you're running using uwsgi look at the python auto reload option:

```
uwsgi --py-autoreload 1
```

Example uwsgi-dev-example.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:5000
master = true
virtualenv = /Users/xxxx/.virtualenvs/sites_env
chdir = /Users/xxx/site_root
module = site_module:register_debug_server()
callable = app
uid = myuser
chmod-socket = 660
log-date = true
workers = 1
py-autoreload = 1
```

site_root/__init__.py

```
def register_debug_server():
    from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = True
    app = DebuggedApplication(app, evalex=True)
    return app
```

Then run:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi-dev-example.ini
```

Note: This example also enables the debugger.

I went this route to mimic production as close as possible with my nginx setup.  Simply running the flask app with it's built in web server behind nginx it would result in a bad gateway error.

Answer (score 21):

For Flask 1.0 until 2.2, the basic approach to hot re-loading is:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=my_application
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

- you should use `FLASK_ENV=development` (not `FLASK_DEBUG=1`)
- as a safety check, you can run `flask run --debugger` just to make sure it's turned on
- the Flask CLI will now automatically read things like `FLASK_APP` and `FLASK_ENV` if you have an [`.env` file in the project root](https://talkpython.fm/episodes/transcript/177/flask-goes-1.0) and [have python-dotenv installed](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/?highlight=flaskenv#environment-variables-from-dotenv)

Comment: `export FLASK_ENV=development` worked for me.  `app.run(debug=True)` does not appear to work.

Comment: @alex strange behavior

Answer (score 18):

```
app.run(use_reloader=True)
```

we can use this, use_reloader  so every time we reload the page our code changes will be updated.

Answer (score 12):

Use this method:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

It will auto-reload the flask app when a code change happens.

Sample code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
   return "Hello World"


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Well, if you want save time not reloading the webpage everytime when changes happen, then you can try the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + R` to reload the page quickly.

Answer (score 11):

I got a different idea:

First:

```py
pip install python-dotenv
```

Install the `python-dotenv` module, which will read local preference for your project environment.

Second:

Add `.flaskenv` file in your project directory. Add following code:

```sh
FLASK_ENV=development
```

It's done!

With this config for your Flask project, when you run `flask run` and you will see this output in your terminal:

[image]

And when you edit your file, just save the change. You will see auto-reload is there for you:

[image]

With more explanation:

Of course you can manually hit `export FLASK_ENV=development` every time you need. But using different configuration file to handle the actual working environment seems like a better solution, so I strongly recommend this method I use.

Comment: Perfect! also, don't forget to include the `FLASK_APP` variable into the `.flaskenv` file.

Comment: this is the neater and more useful answer... thanks

Answer (score 9):

From the terminal you can simply say

```
export FLASK_APP=app_name.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

or in your file

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Dupe of [Auto reloading python Flask app upon code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16344851/5033247)

Answer (score 6):

Enable the reloader in flask 2.2:

```
flask run --reload
```

Answer (score 4):

> command for virtual environment

```
flask run --debug
```

Answer (score 3):

Flask applications can optionally be executed in debug mode. In this mode, two very convenient modules of the development server called the **reloader** and the **debugger** are enabled by default.
When the reloader is enabled, Flask watches all the source code files of your project and automatically restarts the server when any of the files are modified.

By default, debug mode is disabled. To enable it, set a `FLASK_DEBUG=1` environment variable before invoking flask `run`:

```
(venv) $ export FLASK_APP=hello.py for Windows use > set FLASK_APP=hello.py

(venv) $ export FLASK_DEBUG=1 for Windows use > set FLASK_DEBUG=1

(venv) $ flask run

* Serving Flask app "hello"
* Forcing debug mode on
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 273-181-528
```

Having a server running with the **reloader** enabled is extremely useful during development, because every time you modify and save a source file, the server automatically restarts and picks up the change.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this in PyCharm set 'Environment Variables' section to:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

For Flask 'run / debug configurations'.

Comment: For PyCharm Pro users, you can [setup a separate debug config](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-flask-server.html)

Answer (score 1):

To help with fast automatic change in browser:

`pip install livereload`

```
from livereload import Server

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server(app.wsgi_app)
    server.serve()
```

Next, Start your server again:

eg. your `.py` file is ***app.py***

`python app.py`

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better solution is to set the app configuration. For me, I built the tool and then pushed it to a development server where I had to set up a WSGI pipeline to manage the flask web app. I had some data being updated to a template and I wanted it to refresh every X minutes (WSGI deployment for the Flask site through APACHE2 on UBUNTU 18). In your `app.py` or whatever your main app is, add `app.config.update` dictionary below and mark `TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=True`, you will find that any templates that are automatically updated on the server will be reflected in the browser. There is some great documentation on the Flask site for [configuration handling found here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/config/).

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
    TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=True
)
```