# Gunicorn --reload is not working on Ubuntu with local repository

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, flask, gunicorn

I've seen some questions like this and issues on GitHub, but wasn't able to get it to work. My setup is like this:
I have the code locally on Ubuntu 16.04.3

```
├──+messenger
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
```

The contents of the docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
    messenger:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:8000"
        command: >
          gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000
            --access-logfile -
            --reload
            "app:app"
        volumes:
          - ".:/messenger"
```

And no matter what i change inside the `messenger` directory when the app is running, gunicorn never reloads.

I'm using `python:3.6-alpine` to build my image.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue recently. I was using `python:2.7`.
But my mistake was not setting `DEBUG = True` in Django settings.
You might want to enable Debug in Flask too.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes) is similar question.