# http://127.0.0.1:5000/ Flask server displays the same thing even if I change the source code using

Tags: python, flask, terminal

I have written a simple page to be displayed through the link "http://127.0.0.1:5000/". When I first created it is was set to display "Hello World", but now that I have tested to see if it changed the contents of the page if I were to change the code to display "Hello!!!, with three exclamation marks (mind you)".

But it doesn't update it. I have saved the new document and assured it is running on the same port, but it just doesn't update the contents of the webpage.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "hello, World!!!, with three exclamation marks (mind you)"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto reloading python Flask app upon code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes)

Comment: Flush web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1.
    You must reload the webpage each time you change the content

2.
    You must re-run your flask code if the value inside the return has changed.

Comment: I have done both of those things, and it still doesn't display something different

Comment: I have tried to quit (ctrl + c) and then run "python -m flask run" again, but when I reload the page, it doesn't change the return value.

Comment: Try running `python app.py`, or whatever filename of your python file instead of the `python -m flask run`.

Comment: I'll try as soon as I can.

Comment: And, what's the difference between using "python app.py" and "python3 app.py"?

Comment: @CEOV The difference is the version of python. Conventionally, "python" is version 2 or lower. "python3" is version 3.

Comment: I just tried it, both with python and python3, but neither of them seems to work

Comment: @CEOV did you try it with the specifc file? I was talking less about version, and more about specifying the particular file you wish to run. This is because you mentioned you ran `python -m flask run` which relies on environment variables to choose which python file to execute.

Comment: You know what, I might just delete the directory and try it on another, same code just different files.

Comment: Thank you so much man. It works now that I have tried to run it on another directory

Comment: @CEOV sweet. Could you mark my answer correct if it helped you? Thanks ;)