# Does Python(FLASK) have somethink like nodaemon?

Tags: python, flask

with nodaemon code changes will be displayed without rebooting the server, does Python(FLASK) have somthing like that?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Nodemon will automatically restart the server everytime you update your code.  Flask has a similar feature.  To enable it you have to set your  environment to development.  To do so type the following at the command line:

> set flask_env=development

The above works when using a windows cmd line.  If you are using bash try:

$ export FLASK_ENV=development

Then start your server.

See: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/server/