# VS Code not identifying any changes made to the code:

Tags: python, html, flask

Any changes I make to my code aren't doing anything. I am using three things html, flask and python. Any code change I make to my python or html code is not getting implemented on the browser when I am trying to run it.IT is only running older version of the code.
How can I rectify this error of vscode?

Comment: Did you restart your flask instance?

Comment: How can I restart it ?

Comment: Ctrl+C in the terminal that is running it and then start it again.

Comment: I do this every time I make any changes. But still not showing any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're refreshing the page if you're opening a HTML file. If you're accessing the python server make sure to restart it every time you make changes to the code. The way to do it is ctrl+c in the terminal and running the command again. There are ways to make this happen automatically, [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes) for more information

Comment: I do this every time I make any changes. But still not showing any difference.

Comment: Are you saving the files? @RitikaGupta

Comment: Yes. After making changes to my code I always do ctrl + s after that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start your flask server in debug mode?

from Python

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

or from terminal

```
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ flask run
```

Comment: I am doing in debug mode only from the starting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in incognito once. Or try after clearing cache.