# Flask server having to manually stop to run functions

Tags: python, rest, flask, post, web-development-server

I'm currently trying to make a simple flask server that gets input from the local frontend, uses the input to get certain data from a CSV, and then send the data back to the frontend. (I'm brand new to python and web development).

The issue that I'm having is this:

When I run the program, it starts the server and I go onto the frontend and post the input to the backend. It then stores the input in a variable.

I then have to manually stop the server by pressing ctrl-c. This then allows the code after it to run. (The function to get data from the CSV).

Do I then have to automatically restart the server to then send the data to the frontend? This just seems too complicated, and I've been told that you can do all this without stopping the server at all in the first place. I heavily get the sense that I'm missing the trick somewhere, however I'm new to this so pls understand :).

Please let me know if the above makes no sense and I'll try to rephrase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto reloading python Flask app upon code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344756/auto-reloading-python-flask-app-upon-code-changes)

Comment: no, you do not need to restart the server. can you post the relevant code?